# Can't run flutter app on real ios device in debug mode

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I upgraded to fluter 2.5 from 2.2.3. Then I returned it back to version 2.2.3. After that, I cannot start debugging mod on a real ios phone, stuck on Installing and launching. Removing the fluter cache and clearing the fluter does not help.

```
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid kernel binary format version.
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(170)] Could not prepare isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:runtime_controller.cc(382)] Could not create root isolate.
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(576)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all installations and performing a fresh install?

Answer (score 8):

Run this command and it resolve the issue:

flutter run --release

and then follow the steps, if needed, to add trust in your phone. simply go to setting in you phone-> general->device management->trust the apple id

Comment: because sometimes the real devices don't support debug applications as for the cases in my development processes.

Comment: Didn't help, after flutter run --release. I try to launch debug mode, but I receive the same Error( And I can't find this settings in my phone phone-> general->device management->trust the apple id.

Comment: First you have to delete pod, podfile.lock, .symlinks folder along with pod file then do flutter clean and uninstall the app, if already install in your phone
then do flutter run --release and if still the problem persist then open XCode signing the application then try again. hope that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the flow goes like this:

1. plug your device using data cable to you MAC run xcode-> select you
   phone on the top-> (note if the version of your iPhone's OS is not
   recognized then update xcode to 13.1) you can find several videos
   on that.
2. then hit the play button from xcode after some time it will
   ask a key-chain password-> give your MAC's password.
3. then at the end you've to add trust in your phone. simply go to setting in you phone-> general->device management->trush the apple id.
4. you are good to go!

Comment: If launched through xcode, then the application is launched. When I want to run through vs code for debugging my code, it shows the errors that I wrote above. 
3. I cannot find this item in the settings of my phone (